# python raspberry opencv: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'face'

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi3, face-recognition, opencv-contrib

I am using raspberry pi 3. I already installed opencv and it works perfectly. I am trying to use the following command

```
face_recognizer = cv2.face.createLBPHFaceRecognizer()
```

but I get this error:

> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'face'

I did an extensive search and they all told me that I have to installed the opencv_contrib. However, raspberry pi 3 is not letting me install it so easily. I already tried it in windows and it works, but in raspberry nothing.

I always get the following error:

> could not find a version that satisfies the requirement

Here's a picture of everything I've tried:

[image: image with all the examples that I tried]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you figured it out by now or not, but for everyone else out there, as stated on https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/:

> "Note that PyPI does not currently support ARM architecture so you can't install these packages for example on Raspberry Pi"

To use openCV on the raspberry pi, you will need to compile it from the source, here is a great blogpost that will walk you through those steps https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/04/18/install-guide-raspberry-pi-3-raspbian-jessie-opencv-3/.